# Django PasswordChangeDoneView logout after password change

Tags: python, django, passwords, account

I'm using Django's provided `PasswordChangeView` and `PasswordChangeDoneView` from `django.contrib.auth`. After successful password reset, I want the session to be invalidated and log the user out. The Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#session-invalidation-on-password-change) mention that `update_session_auth_hash()` make it so the user does not get logged out after changing passwords. How do I override this and make it so the user DOES get logged out after changing their password?

Comment: How about subclassing `PasswordChangeView` with your own and writing your own `form_valid()`? (look at the source code of `PasswordChangeView`, it's super simple)

Answer (score 1):

Try overriding the `form_valid()` function in your subclass of `PaswordChangeView`.

Here is the function in the original `PaswordChangeView` [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L345):

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.save()
    # Updating the password logs out all other sessions for the user
    # except the current one.
    update_session_auth_hash(self.request, form.user)
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

There you can see the call to `update_session_auth_hash()`. Instead remove it and put the following in your subclass:

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.save()
    self.request.session.flush()
    logout(self.request)
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

That will then *not* call that function.

Comment: You should invalidate the session. And logout the user.

Comment: @dirkgroten I'll delete my answer and you can post a better version including that.

Comment: no just add those two things after `form.save()`: `self.request.session.flush()` and `logout(self.request.user)`.